# Java Swing - Scaling UI to fit window resolution

Tags: java, swing, components, scale

I have made a program that uses null, border, card and some my custom layouts. The window of the program is set to resizable:false. Now I wan't to make full screen mode for my program but the problem is that GUI looks ugly if the size of the screen isn't the one I set. I could implement some kind of scale factor for all the components but the problem is that I have over 2000 components in over 50 classes.

Is there an option to resize whole swing UI for defined factor? That means that the image rendered as UI and all mouse events aswell would be resized.

Comment: 1. Is there an option to resize whole swing UI for defined factor? yes this is basic reason for why LayoutManager exists, then 2. you have to test screen resolution for change/set Font size

Comment: And how do I resize it? Is there a method for JComponent or how do I do this?

Comment: 1. I take that as joke because resize is standard property for all of LayoutManagers, excl. NullLayout, 2. issue is only with Font size, there must be 5-7 different Font size for 5-7 diff. screen size (tlaking about standards from netbook to FHD)

Comment: Resize is standard property of Component and not of the LayoutManager... at least the documentation says so. But the problem is that I have a lot of components and I don't have time to apply resize to all of them. I have tried overriding paintComponent and resizing it and I managed to resize the window, but components didn't resize right and also, I had problems with mouse events

Comment: 1. hmmm then we jumped to extra_terestrial discusion, 2. override getPreferredSize for everything (components???) that hold paintComponent, getHeight/Weight returns always proper coordinates for Dimension from zero to infinity

Comment: out of this thread all good answers in questions tagged by paintComponent are resizable, scallble, settable, a few of them with fits font to desired size

Comment: I will try to do so... even though it will take me a lot of time. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably try to rely on your layout managers. Try to figure out specifically which layouts aren't resizing the way you want, and focus on correcting their behavior instead of trying to manage everything from the top down.

Alternatively, you could keep the size ratio by adding black bars to the top and bottom or left and right of the window when it's in full screen mode. You'll probably still have to play with some of the layouts to get them perfect though.

Having 2000 different components sounds like a usability nightmare, but that's a different issue.

Comment: I like your second idea. I am going to place current main content panel in another and set the size of current to a fixed number. Second panel will have some kind of picture for a wallpaper.